# Get all terms linked to a post and include those who not connected from get_terms and sort

Tags: terms, post-meta

I have the following terms in my WordPress project and my post may have connected with some of them or sometimes all terms.

- A
- B
- C
- D
- E
- F

My first post (example1) is connected with terms A, B and C and second post (example2) connected with A, D,E and F. I found `wp_get_post_terms()` will return all connected terms to a post. But is there a way to show all terms, with connected terms in first position, followed by other terms in the same group?
Example: In the detail page of post example2, I would like to show terms as a filter as follows,

- A
- D
- E
- F
- B
- C

Here B and C are not connected with example 2 but I would like to display in single post in disabled state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get the term id's of the terms assigned to a post, and then exclude those terms from [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

You can try the following (*Just note, the syntax for `get_terms()` changed in v4.5, I'll be using the new syntax*)

```
$args       = [];
$taxonomy   = 'my_tax';
$post_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy ); // Use wp_get_post_terms() if you need special ordering
// Only display the post terms and exclude them if there are terms and no WP_Error
if (    $post_terms
     && !is_wp_error( $post_terms )
) {
    $term_ids = [];
    // Display the list of post terms
    foreach ( $post_terms as $term_object ) {
        // Display term data 

        // Build an array of term ids
        $term_ids[] = $term_object->term_id;
    }

    // Set these id's to the exclude parameter
    $args['exclude'] = $term_ids;
}

// Now we can get the list of all term
$args['taxonomy'] = $taxonomy;
$terms            = get_terms( $args );
// Check if we have terms and no WP_Error
if (    $terms
     && !is_wp_error( $terms )
) {
    // Display the terms
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        // Output the terms as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great with an edit to select exclude terms as below, 
// Now we can get the list of all term
//$args['taxonomy'] = $taxonomy;
//$terms            = get_terms( $args ); 
$terms            = get_terms($taxonomy,$args); 
Thank you